# How to convert Binary data in column to a file?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that contains a `varbinary(max)` column. When I query for this data with SSMS, the column looks like this in what I understand is hexadecimal:

```
0x255044462D312E37
```

So I copied this data and tried writing it to file like this with C#:

```
string hexString = "255044462D312E37"
byte[] file = StringToByteArray(hexString);

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);

    return bytes;
}

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\file.pdf", file);
```

However I cannot open this file with Adobe, it says the file is damaged.

However, I also have an API that is connected to this Database and that serializes and deserialize responses using Newtonsoft. When it does this, it will convert the `varbinary` column to base64. And copying this base and the writing it to disc works just fine like this:

```
string b64 = "JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9M";
byte[] file = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\file.pdf", file);
```

My question is: why can't I convert the hexadecimal string myself?

Comment: `in what I understand is Hexadecimal:` no, that's binary data displayed this way by your client tool, eg SSMS. There's nothing to convert. Just save the bytes to a file without trying to modify them. In fact, you *can't* retrieve that data as a string without either converting it in SQL or on the client.

Comment: Because the binary data is saved as base64 encoded so you first have to decode them. Like you found out by yourself.

Comment: Post your data access code. How do you read that data? Do you use SqlCommand? SqlDataReader.GetBytes? `reader["somfield"]`? You could use [GetStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and save the data directly to a file

Comment: @user743414 that's not Base64 at all. `varbinary` is a *binary* type. What the OP posted is a hex string, not Base64

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yes I know its binary, but doesn't SSMS show it in Hexadecimal, therefore the 0x prefix?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The hexstring could contain anything encoded in anything. So he have to know that. And like he wrote it looks like that it's a base64 encoded string written to a varbinay(max) field.

Comment: @kraft1 yes, that's the point. The data is still binary, not hex. You don't need to decode anything, just read the bytes and store them. Again, post your data access code

Comment: @user743414 that's not what the question says. It says Json.NET serializes to Base64, which has nothing to do with the actual problem

Comment: @kraft1 what are you trying to do? Are you reading from the database? Or did you copy the string from SSMS and now try to decode it? Why not read directly from the database in that case?

Comment: I just need to check files in an database real quick so yes, I selected the rows with SSMS, exported the result to CSV and then copy pasted the string from there into Visual Studio.

Comment: In the last 15 minutes you could have written a simple program to properly extract the data instead of trying to decode what's most likely *truncated* data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you not understand when he wrotes he have an API that read/writes binary data base64 encoded to and from that db? He found the solution already.

Comment: Sadly not because I don't have the proper credentials to read from that db. I have SSMS on another server that uses integrated security, so I cannot do this from my local machine and I cannot isntall anything on the other server.

Comment: @kraft1, are you asking how to quickly executte an ad-hoc query and view the pdf value from the database without writing a C# program? This is easily done in PowerShell with a few lines of code.

Comment: @kraft1 I forgot about Powershell. You can start a PS session from SSMS and execute a query with `Invoke-SqlCmd`, sending the output to a file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`varbinary` is a *binary* type. It stores bytes, not a hex string. `0x255044462D312E37` is how your client tool, eg SSMS or Azure Data Studio display the binary data.

You can read binary data from a query's results through SqlDataReader.GetBytes or [as a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support). Copying from the docs :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT [bindata] FROM [Streams] WHERE [id]=@id", connection)) 
{
    command.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Int64).Value==1;
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(
                   CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)) 
     {
        if (await reader.ReadAsync()) 
        {
           if (!(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0))) 
           {
              using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) 
              {
                 using (Stream data = reader.GetStream(0)) 
                 {
                    await data.CopyToAsync(file);
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
}
```

`ExecuteReaderAsync` must be called with `SequentialAccess`, to avoid caching the entire file in memory.

**Update**

If you can't connect remotely, you can [start a Powershell session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/run-windows-powershell-from-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) from SSMS and use [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) to execute a query. By default `Invoke-SqlCmd` truncates long columns, so you need to use the `-MaxBinaryLength` parameter.

Something like this (haven't tested it) :

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT binaryField from someTable" -ServerInstance "." 
-MaxBinaryLength 1000000000 | Out-File -FilePath "someFile.pdf"
```

Comment: Note `Invoke-SqlCmd` will return a byte array of the specified max size and `Out-File` will format the value as a string. An alternative is to use .NET objects from PS to provide more control like `$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase")
$connection.Open()
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT binaryField from someTable;", $connection)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\file.pdf", ($command.ExecuteScalar()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **stored procedure** in sql-server like below :

I can describe this model by one **example**.
if we have table *Pictures* column *[PictureData]* and need convert this binary to file use below **SP** :

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExportImage] (
   @PicName NVARCHAR (100)
   ,@ImageFolderPath NVARCHAR(1000)
   ,@Filename NVARCHAR(1000)
   )
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ImageData VARBINARY (max);
   DECLARE @Path2OutFile NVARCHAR (2000);
   DECLARE @Obj INT
 
   SET NOCOUNT ON
 
   SELECT @ImageData = (
         SELECT convert (VARBINARY (max), PictureData, 1)
         FROM Pictures
         WHERE pictureName = @PicName
         );
 
   SET @Path2OutFile = CONCAT (
         @ImageFolderPath
         ,'\'
         , @Filename
         );
    BEGIN TRY
     EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream' ,@Obj OUTPUT;
     EXEC sp_OASetProperty @Obj ,'Type',1;
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Open';
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'SaveToFile', NULL, @Path2OutFile, 2;
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Close';
     EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
    END TRY
    
 BEGIN CATCH
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
 END CATCH
 
   SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

you can use this model for any type of file like JPG,PDF,ZIP and etc.

I hope this helpful for you

Comment: Yes this might achieve the desired goal - but at the risk of using ancient, error-prone, fragile OLE automation which is disabled by default. Eating errors is not a good practice either.

Comment: @SMor We use this model in .net-core , we handled errors in a table and fixed them. we have a job for check errors on table(errorlog) . this is a one solution of many models . thanks you for commented, I learned.