PDF's won't load unless they are under 512KB after stored in SQL Server varbinary(MAX)
Trying to create a Blazor application with the MudBlazor framework that allows pdfs to be uploaded to an SQL database. This is a Server side application.
I have a model called Pdfs, using EntityFramework database first. I couldn't get the MudFileUpload to work, or the suggested MudFileUploader, which can be seen on MudBlazor's Component section.
I was using 
With the @LoadFile storing the pointer to the file.
private async Task LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
     file = e.File;
} 

After this, when I submit and it's valid, I use this to store the file inside the byte array that is on the server using the model above.
// Capture the file.
byte[] buffer;
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(maxFileSize))
{
    await file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
    tempPdf.PdfData = buffer;
    
}

I've set maxFileSize above what EFC can typically take, the 512KB. There is an error if I don't place it there, but without it, there isn't an error, it just doesn't load using method below:
    <div>
        <h3>Embedded PDF Viewer</h3>
        <embed src="@(PdfDataUrl)" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1000px" />
    </div>

@code
    // Property to generate the data URL for embedding the PDF
    string ConvertToBase64String(byte[] byteArray) =>
        byteArray != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray) : "";

    // Property to generate the data URL for embedding the PDF
    string PdfDataUrl => $"data:application/pdf;base64,{ConvertToBase64String(pdfByteArray)}";

I've tried other methods for displaying it, which I originally thought was my problem, but if I save then display something below the threshold that EFC has, the 512KB, it is display perfectly fine.
One of the issues I'm assuming is happening is that the file isn't actually being loaded completely into the server due to the restrictions, and I need to asynchronously achieve this, but I don't know where to start at this. I've looked up some applications using loading bars, but none of them are storing directly to a database, or are using EFC.
MudBlazor has a "file upload", but either the button is unresponsive or the components simply do not load. I default to InputFile since it was what was recommended.
Also, I do understand that storing files like this actually in the database isn't typically the best idea since the size of the database can grow exponentially, and I'm already asking to increase the file size for each individual pdf. I understand why this isn't an ideal situation, but the mobility of the database is part of the key factor in this. Storing everything in a single location is part of the takeaway.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"One of the issues I'm assuming is happening is that the file isn't actually being loaded completely into the server due to the restrictions" - I suggest you do some investigation yourself: 1. check if the file is actually saved to the DB in its entirety by measuring the size of data in the column; 2. Check if the file is saved correctly by copying the binary data into a blank file to see if it is a valid PDF.

I knew I could check to see if there was information in the database, but didn't know there was any other way of testing it to see if is the correct size.
I used this in SQL to check the size:
SELECT [PdfDisplayText], DATALENGTH(PdfData) AS total_bytes
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Pdfs]
And found that the size in total bytes were the same size as the files.
I wasn't sure how to copy the binary data to a blank file. I was able to right click and save as on the binary data, but the resulting files did not load and were not the same size as the information above.

FYI Notepad will not work as it will translate characters into ASCII. Try this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462668/how-to-convert-binary-data-in-column-to-a-file (Powershell solution in the first answer)

Next step use a debugger to see if all data is retrieved from the database correctly into byteArray

Alright. I attempted to do the powershell solution, but there was a solution further down with stored procedures which I was familiar with. Couldn't get the powershell command working, but the stored procedure I was using did work.
Tried the same with the larger files and that worked as well. So, my assumption it wasn't loading properly isn't the case it seems like.
Also checked that the data in the database was correctly stored and retrieved by comparing an incoming file to a similar file coming from the database.

So what is left to check?

The data is still not being displayed when using the embedded tag. It's not the storage of the data, but rather the display.
There doesn't seem to be a way to go from binary data to displaying on a page, first it has to be put into a File, but I'm trying to avoid using the filesystem.

Based on what I could find in Google - this looks like a limitation of Blazor. You may need a 3rd party library to overcome it. I am not familiar with Blazor so cannot help your further.

Thank you for your help so far though. Narrowing down the issues and learning another way to test these things has been extremely helpful!
